# Proof without solving equation that if $(1+z)^n = (1-z)^n$ then Re(z) = 0. Did I do it right?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

So, I have to prove that if $(1+z)^n = (1-z)^n$ then $Re(z) = 0$ 'without actually solving the equation.' I see that I can easily transform the equation by interpreting $z$ as $a+bi$: $(1+ a + bi)^n = (1- a - bi)^n$. Then I see that the real parts on both sides must be equal, so

$$1+a = 1-a \Longrightarrow a =-a$$
$$ a = 0 \Longrightarrow Re(z) = 0 $$

And here comes my question - is that any good? I mean it seems too simple, I think I don't understand something.

Comment: You seem to have made the mistake of writing $ (1 + a + bi)^n = (1+a)^n + (bi)^n $, which is false.

Comment: The real part of $(1+a+ib)^n$ is not $1+a$!!!

Comment: Then what is? I was sure that the real part of the left hand side of the equation is $1 + a$.

Comment: @theman, what's the real part of $(1+i)^2$?

Comment: Making assertions with "I am sure that..." without evidence or logical argument is not, generally speaking, how to engage in mathematical discourse, on math stack exchange or elsewhere.

Comment: @JakeMirra, he said he "was" sure before when he did the problem. He wasn't saying copper.hat was wrong.

Comment: Wow, I did not mean to offend anybody. I am pretty new to the whole concept of complex algebra. Just wanted to express my surprise and gratitude. If not copper.hat I would still be wrong.

Comment: I could have sworn the comment said "am" before.  If I'm right, then that would be a silly way to communicate.  If I am wrong, then I'm sorry for misreading the comment.  At any rate, I wasn't offended, just making a genuine attempt to help @theman communicate better.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The question may be easily answered.

Since $(1+z)^n = (1-z)^n, ~~ |1+z|^n = |1 - z|^n.$

Therefore, the distance from $z$ to $1$ equals the distance from $z$ to $-1$.

Therefore, $z$ lies on the perpendicular bisector between $1$ and $-1$.

Therefore the real part of $z$ is equal $0.$

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you just explain to me why is that you can express $(1+z)^n$ as $|1+z|^n$?

Comment: @theman Basic theorem in complex analysis: $|z \times w| = |z| \times |w|$.  Therefore, $$|(1+z)^n| ~=~ |1 + z|^n.$$

Comment: @theman, $(1+z)^n \ne |1+z|^n$. What user2661923 was doing was taking the absolute value of both sides of the equation $(1+z)^n = (1-z)^n$.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Thanks for filling the gap.  I overlooked your point.