# Problem : $(1+z)^n=(1-z)^n$ $\Rightarrow $ $Re(z) =0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying, but I found $im(z) =0$

I want to know where is my mistake

My attempt :

$(1+z)^n=(1-z)^n$

We put $z =e^{i\theta}$

$(1+e^{i\theta})^n=(1-e^{i\theta})^n$

$\Leftrightarrow $$(-e^{-i\pi} +e^{i\theta})^n=(-e^{-i\pi} - e^{i\theta})^n$

$\Leftrightarrow $$(e^{\frac{i\theta-\pi}{2}}(e^{\frac{i\theta+\pi}{2}}-e^{\frac{-i(\theta+\pi) }{2}}) ) ^n=(-((e^{\frac{i\theta-\pi}{2}}(e^{\frac{i\theta+\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{-i(\theta+\pi) }{2}}) ) ^n$

$\Leftrightarrow $$(e^{\frac{i\theta-\pi}{2}}(e^{\frac{i\theta+\pi}{2}}-e^{\frac{-i(\theta+\pi) }{2}}) ) ^n=(e^{-\pi} ((e^{\frac{i\theta-\pi}{2}}(e^{\frac{i\theta+\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{-i(\theta+\pi) }{2}}) ) ^n$

$\Leftrightarrow $ $ (sin (\frac{\theta +\pi}{2}) e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}) ^n=(cos(\frac{\theta+\pi}{2})(e^{i\frac{\theta-\pi}{2} - \pi})^n$

$\Leftrightarrow $$-sin(\frac {\theta}{2}) =cos(\frac {\theta}{2}) $ and $e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}=e^{i\frac{\theta-\pi}{2} - \pi}$

$e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}=e^{i\frac{\theta-\pi}{2} - \pi}$$\Rightarrow $$cos(\frac {\theta}{2})  +isin(\frac {\theta}{2}) =cos(\frac{\theta-\pi}{2} - \pi) +isin(\frac{\theta-\pi}{2} - \pi)  $

$\Rightarrow $ $cos(\frac {\theta}{2})  +isin(\frac {\theta}{2}) =-cos(\frac {\theta-\pi}{2})  - isin(\frac {\theta-\pi}{2})$

$\Rightarrow $ $cos(\frac {\theta}{2})  +isin(\frac {\theta}{2})=-sin(\frac {\theta}{2}) +icos(\frac {\theta}{2})$

We know that:$-sin(\frac {\theta}{2}) =cos(\frac {\theta}{2}) $

So $2 isin(\frac{\theta}{2}))= 0$

$\Rightarrow $ $im(z) =0$

Comment: First of all sir,  z=eiθ implies that the modulus of the complex number is 1.

Comment: Do you mean  \begin{equation*}
| z| =1
\end{equation*}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895921/proof-without-solving-equation-that-if-1zn-1-zn-then-rez-0-did-i

Comment: I will try to find your mistake, give me a few minutes.

Comment: First and foremost, you are trying to find $z$ such that it satisfies that equation. Why should it be true that such a $z$ must have $|z| = 1$? For example , $z=0$ satisfies the equation but does not have $|z| = 1$? Furthermore, there are other issues : for example, the second and third line don't have the same LHS : you go from having $i \pi$ in the exponent to having only $\pi$ without an $i$ multiplied, so something goes wrong there. \

Comment: You have to fix bracketing first.

Comment: Whether or not your question is closed, please do not deface it

Comment: Do not vandalize your own question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, observe that $$(1+z)^n=(1-z)^n\implies |1+z|=|1-z|$$
Now, we square the equation and use the fact that $|a|^2 = a\overline{a}$ for $a\in\mathbb{C}$.
$$|1+z|^2=|1-z|^2\iff (1+z)(1+\overline{z})=(1-z)(1-\overline{z})\iff z+\overline{z} = 0=2\:\text{Re}(z)$$
The problem is solved.

Comment: You cannot assume $|z|=1$. You have also missed a lot of brackets.

Comment: Have you shown that $|z|$ must equal $1$?

Comment: This relationship should be true no matter what |z|

Comment: Even if you manage to show that the claim holds when $|z|=1$, it does NOT imply that the claim holds for all $z$.

Comment: I'd suggest you fix bracketing and go over your proof once again. I also see that you have used $a^n = b^n\implies a = b$. This is not true in general, especially when $a,b$ are allowed to be complex.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
\left( 1+e^{i\theta }\right)^{n} =\left( 1-e^{i\theta }\right)^{n}\\
\frac{1+e^{i\theta }}{1-e^{i\theta }} =e^{i\frac{2k\pi }{n}}\\
e^{i\theta } =\frac{e^{i\frac{2k\pi }{n}} -1}{e^{i\frac{2k\pi }{n}} +1} =itan\left(\frac{k\pi }{n}\right)\\
\end{gather*}
Hence, z is purely imaginary.
Hope you find this method simpler and hope this answers your question.